# C++/cli Clickable invisible button

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

As suggested, how could I make a button in c++/cli (Windows Form) invisible and clickable?

I can make it invisible with `this->button1->Visible = false;`

When clicked it changes a picture changes. Sadly, while invisible, I might as well not have it, since it isn't clickable in this state.

How can I make this invisible button clickable?

Answer (score 0):

To make things not visible but still clickable in WinForms, I'd generally start by setting [`ForeColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) and [`BackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms158232.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) to [`Transparent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.transparent.aspx?cs-lang=cpp). However, a button also has things like borders, a dotted line when it has keyboard focus, that type of thing, and I'm not sure you can set all of those colors.

Does it have to be a Button? A plain [`Control`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) has a much plainer visual look, which can more easily be made invisible, but it still has a [`Click`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) event. Would that work for you?

Comment: I've had ForeColor and BackColor as transparent but, it's still looks exactly the same. Nothing is transparent. And yes, it is important that the button is transparent. It is a custom designed UI I made and to keep the look consistent, so it is needed.

Comment: But does it have to be a `Button`? Would it work to make the invisible thing a `Control`, or some other WinForms type? Would it work to have there be nothing there at all, and click on the background of the `Form` itself?

Comment: I'll have to look into controls as it's not something I'm familiar with. From what I'm seeing, it could be an answer. Thank you.